# How to get an attibute from another attribute in the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to achieve is get an attibute from another attribute in the same element. For example:

```
<script>
$("#step1").click(function() {
    // Get the attribute 'next' and get its value.
});
</script>

<button id="step1" next=".openNextModal">
```

Comment: FYI: `next` is not a valid attribute for a button

Comment: I suppose the proper way of making custom element attributes is by using the data- prefix. I'm aware that `next` is not a valid attribute. @adeneo

Comment: use `data-next` instead which is a valid HTML5 custom data attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your need to use `attr()`

```
<script>
$("#step1").click(function() {
    // Get the attribute 'next' and get its value.
    var next = $( this ).attr( 'next' );

    //if you are looking for next attribute value of the next element              
    console.log( $( next ).attr( 'next' )); 

    //if this is an input element and you are looking for its value
    console.log( $( next ).val()); 

    //if this is an not input element and you are looking for its html
    console.log( $( next ).html()); 

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like following.

```
$("#step1").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('next'));
});
```